# How to identify drive of Azure Virtual Machine with how it is shown at Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, disk

I am trying to identify which drive matches from Azure Virtual Machine with what is shown on the Azure Portal site.

I am trying to increase the size of one drive (**H:**\ drive) in VM from Azure Portal site.

This is how it shows up in VM:
[image]

This is how it shows up in Azure Portal site:
[image]

Where do I go about finding the right one to upgrade (from Azure Portal site)?

Currently, **H:**\ drive has 2 TB for the capacity, and I am trying to increase to 4 TB.

**Modified/Added this later (after I got the feedback)**:
[image]

**Modified/Added this later (after I got the feedback)**:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to identify which drive matches from Azure Virtual Machine***

I have created azure virtual machine and attached a new disk like below.

[image]

In ***Disk management*** to make understand on your disk -> right click -> properties -> you can see LUN number -> in my case LUN8 is represent as disk 5

[image]

[image]

My disk 4 is identify in E drive as LUN 7

[image]

Now in disk click on virtual disk. suppose You want to increase size of azure8 (my disk name)

[image]

If you click on 5 -> 5 is represent as disk 5 (G)drive as location on LUN 8 in my portal LUN 8 is azure8 disk name this way u can identify which drive is represent on which disk

[image]

Additionally, To note the drives while allocating volume I have added to remember 2s for disk2 for particular LUN
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following solution might help you with finding out which LUN number correlates to your 'H' partition. It is not very optimized but after a quick test should yield the desired result.

The commands are:

```
Get-Disk
Get-Partition -DiskNumber 2
$mydisk = Get-Disk 2
$mydisk.Location
```

The output should provide the LUN. DiskNumber 2 was arbitrarily chosen and you might have to try all disk numbers provided by "Get-Disk" to obtain the disk with the correct partition (or of course use some other method).

See the image below for my results:
[image]

[This MS Learn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-disk?view=windowsserver2022-ps) provides more information about the commands.
Hopefully this helps.

Kind regards

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried the PS and got this so far (I just added the image on the original post for your reference). It looks like it is DiskNumber 3. But, I do not see in the Azure Portal. Why is that?

Comment: What you need is the 'LUN' value.
To obtain that you can do the following:

  
`$hdisk = Get-Disk 3  
$hdisk.Location  `  

Could you provide the information that is provided by the "$hdisk.Location" output? It should look similar to what is found in the image in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Please see my additional images I added. By looking at the result, where does LUN 2 belong? Did I do something wrong with my PS command?